# Are windows compatible components compatible with Ubuntu?

Tags: graphics, compatibility

Well I'm building a computer and the components are windows compatible in description, so if i get them and run Ubuntu in BIOS, will they work?

Comment: Please tell me if you know.

Comment: Please tell us, what are these components?

Comment: @markkirby Converted into an answer.

Comment: "Windows Compatible" just tells you that they have Windows drivers. For the most part, Ubuntu is compatible with just about anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As other answers have stated, unfortunately the moniker "Windows Compatible" promises only that the hardware will work in windows.

Hardware support in the linux kernel is and has been very good for recent years.

Most graphics hardware from Intel, AMD and NVIDIA will usually worth, but still check, sometimes drivers for cutting edge cards are a bit late on linux, and sometimes older cards have limited support. All intel and amd x86 based processors will work, and additionally any motherboards which support them, along with memory which is standardised and will also always work.

Harddrives will always work.

In general however I would still recommend checking online for each piece of hardware you plan to purchase, and see if anyone has mentioned any incompatibilities.

If you plan to use wifi, I would defiantly suggest checking this, and any dedicated sound cards (rare these days), or any other obscure hardware you intend on purchasing.

Be aware that any hardware which come with specialised software will probably, unless stated not work, or not work to their full potential (I'm thinking gaming mice and keyboards here).

Specialist hardware such as drawing tablets, also are worth checking first.

tldr; If you care about wasting money, check everything just to be sure, but generally these days most things work on linux.

Answer (score 6):

Windows and Linux are not comparable.

*"Windows compatible"* tells you nothing about *"Ubuntu compatible"* and the other way round.

Answer (score 2):

Hello and welcome on Ask Ubuntu!

All of those components which has the corresponding drivers in kernel or has proprietary support are compatible. **Windows and GNU/Linux systems have different structures so drivers are not universal** - except for some network card you can try to get working with NDISWrapper.

Since your question has the tag 'graphics' I assume you would like to know that does your VGA have support. In case you have Ati/AMD or nVidia card or an Intel IGP I can surely tell you - absolutely have! (aside from rare exceptions, but without any clue that is the most detailed answer I can tell).

Comment: @markkirby Thanks for the reference, now it should be fine, I hope :)

Answer (score 1):

The words "compatible with windows" guarantees to you that parts support Windows, but this does not exclude the compatibility with Ubuntu. The answer is therefore a maybe. Not all components are compatible with Ubuntu and Linux. I suggest you do a search to see if the components are compatible.